# Objective-C instance variables accessor methods

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to get more into detail with Objective-C programming language.

Right now I have a question regarding calling `[self]` when setting values.

The Apple documentation says "If you do not use self., you access the instance variable directly. (...)"

So assuming I have a dog object that has an instance variable `NSString *name`.

I create a setter for that instance variable like this without using the `[self]` keyword:

```
(void)setName:(NSString *)_name
{
  name = _name;
}
```

When I alternatively create a setter WITH the [self] keyword it looks like this:

```
(void)setName:(NSString *)_name
{
  self->name = _name;
}
```

In the main-method I create a new dog object and set and return its name value:

```
Dog *myDog = [[Dog alloc] init];

myDog.name = @"Yoda";

NSLog(@"name of the dog: %@", myDog.name);
```

In both cases I get a return value of Yoda. But where is the difference between an instance variable call with and without [self] technically? Is it that I call the same variable (memory) just without using the setter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` is an implicit reference to the object itself, and generally you only really need to specify it when a parameter and an instance variable have the same name, for example if you had:

```
(void)setName:(NSString *)name
{
  self->name = name;    // self used here to differentiate between param and ivar
}
```

However, you need to be careful with your naming conventions and implementation of methods:

1. Generally a leading underscore is used as a convention to name the instance variables, not the parameter passed to a method.
2. In order to set the `NSString *` object, generally you are going to need to `retain` it in order to take ownership of the object and to avoid it getting released (which will cause an exception when you access it later).

Therefore your `setName` method should look more like this:

```
// _name is the instance variable
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name
{
    [name retain];
    [_name release];
    _name = name;
}
```

This is only true if you are using MRR, instead of ARC, but you don't specify that so I'll assume you are using MRR.

Comment: Thanks that was quite clear to me for the first part. I don't get why you `retain` the `name` object in the setter. I would guess that I need the `name` object only in the setter and after I assign it to the instance variable `_name` it can be released while `_name` should be retained for later use?

Comment: @MrBr It all depends on whether you are using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC).  If you are then you don't have to worry and your version will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between your 2 examples, in both cases you are modifying the instance variable directly

by self it is meaning `self.name` which uses the setter method `[self setName:someValue];`

`self->name` just means that it is accessing an instance variable so

```
self->ivar = someVal;
//is the same as
ivar = someVal;
```

Comment: `self.name` is the same as `[self setName:name]`, not `self->name`.

Comment: @trojanfoe correct, thats what i said, i'll edit to make it clearer

Comment: ok so in both cases I am operating on the same variable (so to say the same place I allocated in memory)?

Comment: @MrBr correct, both of your examples are both accessing the ivar directly. the difference in using self.myProperty = ... is that you get the synthesized setters (assuming you havent overriden them) which means you get memory management in a non ARC environment, as well as other things like KVO notifications